# Form not Displaying fields (Not seeing a forms.Forms object) - Django 1.11.8

Tags: python, django, django-forms, django-templates, django-views

I am trying to display a simple form (3 fields) on a webpage using Django but no fields are displaying - see code below.

I've gone through the Django doc, MDN doc, most of the StackOverflow posts here, but it's still not working.

I was able to see, using {% debug %}, that there is no object `EmailInput` on the page.

At this point, I am not sure what is causing this issue. Any help would be very much appreciated.

Thanks

---

**forms.py**

```
from django import forms

class EmailInput(forms.Form):
    email = forms.EmailField()
    first_name = forms.CharField()
    last_name = forms.CharField()
```

**views.py**

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from .models import journalEntry
from django.http import HttpResponseRedirect
from django.urls import reverse

from journal.forms import EmailInput


def index(request):
    post = journalEntry.objects.filter(status__exact='f')
    latest_post = journalEntry.objects.filter(status__exact='f').order_by('-created')[:5]

    return render(request, 'journal_index.html', context = {'post':post,'latest_post':latest_post})

def email_input(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = EmailInput(request.POST)

        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('journal-index'))   
    else:
        form = EmailInput()

    return render(request, 'journal_index.html',{'form':form})
```

**journal_index.html**

```
{% extends "base_generic.html" %}
{% block content %}
    <form action="" method="post">
        {% csrf_token %}
        {{ form }}
        <input type="submit" value="Submit"/>
    </form>
{% endblock content %}
```

**urls.py**
    from django.conf.urls import url
    from . import views

```
urlpatterns = [
        url(r'^$', views.index, name='journal-index'),
        ]
```

Comment: You have only one url in `urls.py`?

Comment: Yes, that’s the part I was not sure about. I want to display my form on my app index page (in this case /journal/). But I also want to use my index view in this same page. From what I understand, you can only pass 1 view to 1 url. I tried to add another url in my urls.py referencing my email_input view with url(r’^$,...,...) that did not change anything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to display it in the index page then you have to send it as a context variable in your `index` function. And now it will be available in your `journal_index.html` template file.

```
def index(request):
    post = journalEntry.objects.filter(status__exact='f')
    latest_post = journalEntry.objects.filter(status__exact='f').order_by('-created')[:5]
    form = EmailInput()
    context = {
        'post': post,
        'latest_post': latest_post,
        'form': form
    }

    return render(request, 'journal_index.html', context = context)
```

The code from your `email_input` function is not called anywhere so there is no way this form could be displayed. Also you have to figure out where do you want to display this form. If you don't want to display it together with the stuff from your index page then you would have to create a new template file, add the form there and add a new url path to display that page.

Comment: Thanks. Can't believe it was that simple.

Answer (score 0):

It is because you are not even calling email_input.
you need to bind it to a url like this  
`urlpatterns = [
        url(r'^$', views.email_input),
        ]`